# ObservableCollections not working yet in MAUI?

Tags: c#, observablecollection, maui

I tried MAUI and MVVM with an `ObservableCollection`.

- Created new MAUI project
- Added ViewModel with `BindingContext`
- Bound `StackLayout` to an `ObservableCollection`
- Added Item to the Collection on Button click

Nothing changes. "Foo" and "Bar" still here although a third element is added on button click.

**My project:**

Replaced first label in the (default) new project with

```
<StackLayout
    Grid.Row="0"
    BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Foo}">

    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Text="{Binding .}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    
</StackLayout>
```

Added

```
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:MainPageViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainPageViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> Foo { get; } = new() { "Foo", "Bar" };
    }
```

Added in the button click (added as first element to avoid missing changes because of UI height problems, but nothing changes when I try Add() instead):

```
(this.BindingContext as MainPageViewModel).Foo.Insert(0, "Baz");
```

Is there any info if ObservableCollections should work already?
Or (coming from WPF) is there something I have to change for MAUI/Xamarin?

Comment: Did you try `x:Bind`? Did you set the `DataContext`?

Comment: MAUI/Xamarin does not know either `x:Bind` or `DataContext`

Comment: What version did you try this with? I would think this already works, then again, it's still in preview, something might still be missing to connect the dots.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis preview 6 with VS 2022 preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce what you're seeing and I 100% can. The initial value shows up, but not when adding something. Inspecting the Live Visual Tree though, we see that the `Label`s do actually get added. The `ObservableCollection` works, it seems the layout just doesn't update.

Even with a call to force the layout on the `StackLayout` it won't update to it seems, so it looks like the layout isn't working properly at this point.

Looking at the [roadmap](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Roadmap#net-maui-in-net-6-preview-7-august-2021) there is still some layout work to do, it will probably be fixed for preview 7.

[image: Reproduction screenshot]

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. As a MAUI/Xamarin beginner, it helps to know if it's up to you or not.

Comment: Totally understandable. Glad I was able to help out!

Comment: Almost one year on (June 2022) and this is still a problem. Any fix available?

Comment: I think I have just hit this issue and we are now on GA! If I understand this right if you are bound to an ObservableCollection<MyClass> and this is bound to a <CollectionView> the items display fine, but if you change any property in an item in the list then the change is not reflected through to the xaml. Or am I misreading. It certainly seems to be an issue I am facing. Any workarounds? Is this reported in the Maui github?

Comment: That sounds more like the expected behaviour where MyClass does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works.

I suggest to create a model.

Your model should implement **ObservableObject**.

```
Public class Post: ObservableObject
{
        private string title= String.Empty;
        public string Title
        {
            get
            {
                return this.title;
            }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref title, value);

            }
        }

}
```

Your view model should implement **ObservableObject**

```
public partial class PostViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    ObservableCollection<Post> posts;

}
```

Afterwards, any modification on the property Title will render the ui accordingly.
(Tested on Visual Studio 17.3.6)

More information can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/observableobject).